# Given a vector of intervals output any one number within the interval that has been overlapped the most times

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Say we define intervals like this

```
struct Interval {
  float start;
  float end;
  Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}
  Interval(float s, float e) : start(s), end(e) {}
```

};

How to output any one number within the interval that has been overlapped the most times?

For example, given [1.2,3.4],[2.6,6.8],[8.5,10.2],[15.1,18.7]
we can output any number within [2.6, 3.4] like 2.7 because [2.6, 3.4] is the interval that has been overlapped the most times(twice).

My idea is to sort the intervals by "start" and then run a for loop through all intervals. For each interval we count how many "start"s of following intervals that are smaller or equal to its "end", and update the maximum value each loop.

But this looks like a O(n2) solution can we do better?

Comment: How about stacking the ending intervals in a priority queue based on the ending position while moving along the range, popping off the nearest ending intervals or pushing the next starting interval depending on which is closest while keeping a running "overlap" count?

Comment: Your idea of sorting the intervals by start time can be made to work in O(n log n) time if you also have a second list of intervals sorted by the end times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple `O(n log n)` solution which uses events and sweep line:

1. There are two types of events: a start of an interval and the end of an interval.
2. We can sort all events by their coordinate(if two events have the same coordinate, the one that corresponds to a start of an interval should go earlier. If they are of the same type, they can go in any order).
3. Now we can iterate over the sorted array of the intervals and add +1 to a counter when we see a start of an interval and -1 when we see an end. The maximum value of the counter is the answer.
4. Why is it correct? At any moment, the value of the counter is the number of intervals that start before the current position and end after it. That's exactly what we need to maximize.

The time complexity is `O(n log n)`(we just sort the array of events and then make one linear pass over it).

Comment: And you get correct handling of negative intervals as a bonus. Cute.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your algorithm correctly but in the example [2.6, 3.4] is not one of the original intervals? And we want a number within this range like 2.7 or 3.1

Comment: @user3692521 The problem statement says that we can output any number from this interval. It is easy to prove that there is always an end point of at least one of the given intervals which fits.

Comment: Oh I got it this is clever!